# Problem Involving Cubes and Lines

Tags: geometry, 3d

Let $ABCDEFGH$ be a cube of side length 5, as shown. Let $P$ and $Q$ be points on $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{AE}$, respectively, such that $AP = 2$ and $AQ = 1$. The plane through $C$, $P$, and $Q$ intersects $\overline{DH}$ at $R$. Find $DR$.
[image: Diagram]

---

Here's my thoughts so far.  Since triangles APQ and DPR are similar, we can use the proportion $\frac{2}{1}=\frac{7}{DR}$, therefore DR=3.5.  Is this correct?   Thanks!  Please explain if not correct.

Comment: Which 'triangle' DPR do you mean? If you're intending to 'unfold' the cube so that faces ABFE and AEHD are parallel, then you're making the (not jnecessarily warranted) assumption that PQR is a straight line so that DPR is actually a triangle! If you mean the triangle DPR in three-space, then (a) your length DP is wrong, and (b) I don't believe that DPR is actually similar to APQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong. The proper similar triangles are $APQ$ and $DCR$.

Simply extend the segments $CP$ and $RQ$ until they intersect at a common point which is the common intersection point $S$ of the planes $ABCD, \, ADHE$ and $PQRC$ which is on the line $AD$. In other words $CP, \, RQ$ and $DA$ intersect in $S$. Then you see that $APQ$ and $DCR$ are similar triangles  because a homothety with center $S$ maps one to the other. And then simply 
$$\frac{DR}{AQ} = \frac{CD}{PA}$$ which turns into
$$DR = \frac{DR}{1} = \frac{5}{2} = 2.5$$

Actually, it is probably easier to observe that $AQ \parallel DR \,$, $\,\, AP \parallel CD$ and $PQ \parallel CR$, so triangles $APQ$ and $DCR$ are similar.

Answer (score 1):

Let we put a reference system with the origin at $A$, the $x$-axis along $AB$, the $y$-axis along $AD$ and the $z$-axis along $AE$. Then we have a plane $\pi$ through
$$ P(2;0;0),\quad C(5;5;0),\quad Q(0;0;1) $$
with equation
$$ 5x-3y+10z = 10 $$
hence if $x=0$ and $y=5$ (corresponding to $D$) we have $z=\color{red}{\large\frac{5}{2}}$ (corresponding to $DR$).